# PHP Regex match specific site url with params

Tags: php, regex, url

I have some text, and I need to wrap my site urls into  links.

Example text: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, vitasya-le.work consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. http://vitasya-le.work Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. habrahabr Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. vitasya-le.work"

I need to match these URLs:

- `http://vitasya-le.work`
- `vitasya-le.work`
- `http://www.vitasya-le.work`
- `vitasya-le.work/topic/view/33113-topic-title`
- `http://vitasya-le.work/topic/view/33113-topic-title`
- `http://www.vitasya-le.work/topic/view/33113-topic-title`
- `.vitasya-le.work`

I have `((\S+|\s)vitasya-le.work(\s|\S+|$))` pattern but it doesn't match all combinations

Comment: Eh, `.vitasya-le.work` is not a valid URL...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a regex that should match all of them:

```
$regex = '/(?:http:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?vitasya-le\.work(?:\/[\w\-]+)*\/?/';
```

And some tests:

```
$tests = array(
    'http://vitasya-le.work',
    'vitasya-le.work',
    'http://www.vitasya-le.work',
    'vitasya-le.work/topic/view/33113-topic-title',
    'http://vitasya-le.work/topic/view/33113-topic-title',
    'http://www.vitasya-le.work/topic/view/33113-topic-title',
);
echo '<pre>';
foreach ($tests as $test) {
    preg_match($regex, $test, $match);
    if (empty($match)) {
        echo 'Did NOT match: ', $test, "\n";
    } else {
        echo 'Match: ', $test, "\n";
    }
}

$test2 = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, vitasya-le.work consectetur '
.'adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore '
.'et dolore magna aliqua. http://vitasya-le.work Ut enim ad '
.'minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi '
.'ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. habrahabr Duis aute irure '
.'dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore '
.'eu fugiat nulla pariatur. vitasya-le.work';

preg_match_all($regex, $test2, $matches);
var_dump(array_pop($matches));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$text = preg_replace(
    '/((http:\/\/(www.)?|\.))?vitasya-le\.work[\S]*/',
    '<a href="$0">$0</a>',
    $text
);
```

Steps:

- optionally match `http://` optionally followed by `www.`, or just `.`
- then match the main part of the URL
- match any sequence of characters after the main part that aren't space characters